# Closest line from above optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm interested in solving the following problem: finding the line $ax + b$ that is the closest to a cloud of points $(x_i, y_i)$ but always above all the points.
I assumed that the absolute values (or the squares) were not necessary in that case and that the problem could be reduced to a linear program of the form:

$\min_{a,b} {\sum_{i=1}^n {(a x_i + b - y_i)}} \text{ s.t. } \forall i \in [1,n], a x_i + b \geq y_i$

I have translated it to a standard LP problem and tried to solve it with scipy, with the following parameters:

$x = (a, b)$

$c = \begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}\\
n
\end{pmatrix}$

$A_{ub} = \begin{pmatrix}
-x_1 & -1\\
\dots&\dots\\
-x_n & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

$b_{ub} = \begin{pmatrix}
-y_1\\
\dots\\
-y_n
\end{pmatrix}$

But it didn't work, it always returns $a = 0$. Is my problem ill-posed?

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I tried your model and it works fine on a random data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your model is correct and suspect an implementation issue.

Consider this simple random data set:

[image]

The model yields $a=0.691$, $b=5.230$:

[image]

Comment: Oops, you're right, I created b_ub with y[i] intead of -y[i]... I feel so ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

From

$$
a x + b y + c = 0\Rightarrow y+\frac{a x+ c}{b} \le 0\Rightarrow y + \alpha + \beta x \le 0
$$

so we have the problem

$$
\max_{\alpha,\beta} \alpha, \ \ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \ \ y_k + \alpha +\beta x_k \le 0,\ \ k =1,\cdots,n
$$

or

$$
\max_{\alpha,\beta}(1,0)(\alpha,\beta)',\ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \left(\matrix{1&x_1\\ \vdots&\vdots\\ 1& x_n
}\right)\left(\matrix{\alpha\\ \beta}\right)+\left(\matrix{y_1\\ \vdots\\ y_n}\right)\le 0
$$

To handle this maximization problem with Linear Programming care mus be taken regarding the sign of $\alpha,\beta$ which should be nonnegative. To avoid this problem we introduce two new variables

$$
\bar\alpha = \alpha-\alpha_{min}\ge 0\\
\bar\beta = \beta-\beta_{\min}\ge 0
$$

so the problem is transformed into

$$
\max_{\bar\alpha\ge 0,\bar\beta\ge 0}(1,0)(\bar\alpha,\bar\beta)',\ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \left(\matrix{1&x_1\\ \vdots&\vdots\\ 1& x_n
}\right)\left(\matrix{\bar\alpha+\alpha_{min}\\ \bar\beta+\beta_{min}}\right)+\left(\matrix{y_1\\ \vdots\\ y_n}\right)\le 0
$$

Included a MATHEMATICA and python scripts which handle the calculation process

```
n = 15;
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];

amin = -10;
bmin = -10;
A = -Transpose[{Transpose[data][[1]], Table[1, n]}];
B =  Transpose[{Transpose[data][[1]], Transpose[data][[2]],Table[1, n]}].{amin, 1, bmin};
lsol = LinearProgramming[{0, -1}, A, B];

gr1 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Thick];
l1 = y + alpha x + beta /. Thread[{alpha, beta} -> lsol + {amin, bmin}]
gr2 = ContourPlot[l1 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> Red];
Show[gr1, gr2, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n    = 10

data = []
for k in range(n):
    xk = rd.uniform(-1,1)
    yk = rd.uniform(-1,1)
    data.append([xk, yk])

A = []
B = []

C = [0., -1.]
x = []
y = []

for point in data:
    xk = point[0]
    yk = point[1]
    x.append(xk)
    y.append(yk)
    A.append([xk, 1.])
    B.append(-yk)

res = linprog(C, A_ub = A, b_ub = B, bounds = (None, None))

a = res.x[0] 
b = res.x[1]
print([a,b])
plt.xlim([-1,1])
plt.ylim([-1,1.2])
plt.plot(x,y,'o',color = 'black')

xs = list(np.linspace(-1., 1., 100))

ys = []
for x0 in xs:
    ys.append(-(x0*a + b))

plt.plot(xs, ys, linestyle ='-')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand your change of variable. But anyway, what was wrong in my approach?

Comment: $\min_{a,b} {\sum_{i=1}^n {(a x_i + b - y_i)}}$

Comment: Why? I want to minimize the distance between the line and the points, while having the line standing above the points.

Comment: We need to determine a line that separates a half plane that contains the data. As simple as this.

Comment: I tried your system, I didn't get the correct values for a and b.

c = np.array([1, 0])

A_ub = np.array([(1, -x[i]) for i in range(n)])
b_ub = np.array([y[i] for i in range(n)])

linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub)

Comment: Please. Have a look at the modifications.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But in the end, you transformed my problem into a more complex one (with the introduction of slack variables).

Comment: Slack variables are needed when using the standard simplex algorithm to solve the linear programming problem. In scipy we can overcome this problem using the parameter `bounds = (None, None)`. I changed the python script including this capability. The purpose in the answer was to show the linear programming conventions.